# How to disconnect from specific WiFi network (while remembering the connection)

Tags: macos, wifi, network

I would like to disconnect from my WiFi network on OS X Lion without having the computer to forget the network. So basically I'm looking for a way to just disconnect and connect to a specific WiFi network at will.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 8):

You can disconnect from the current wireless network without turning wireless off by running the following command on the command line:

```
sudo /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -z
```

Comment: Thanks very much --- but is there _seriously_ no way to do this from the GUI?

Answer (score 2):

Would setting up different locations under Network preferences, each having different way out settings be an option? You'd 'sort of' be disconnecting.

Answer (score 2):

I know that it's old question but maybe someone is looking for better solution.

I've just found that you can detach from a WiFi network by <kbd>Opt/Alt</kbd>-clicking on the Wifi icon and then selecting the appropriate option in the dropdown.

Comment: That Alt key hides all kinds of suprises in OSX

Answer (score 0):

Your router may also offer a user interface which offers a way to disconnect from the wifi network.  I just tested it out with mine and it worked fine.  I also tested the command line prompt described above, and that worked, too.